# ClickOnce Install Error: Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed

Tags: .net, clickonce

I am seeing the following error message when trying to install my application using ClickOnce.

> Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.

I only get this error when I am trying to install the production version and I have a QA version installed with the same version number. I use a different product name for the two environments, so I do not see why there would be a conflict.

Now, for the really weird part. If I take a copy of the [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) directory that is hosting the application, and run the exact same set of mage commands, except this time use "QA2" for the name parameter, I can install a second copy of the application. One is called QA and the other is QA2. Everything else about them is identical, but yet, I still cannot install the production version that has a completely different name. What do I need to do to avoid this error?